# Rigorous definition and relations between point/vector/affine space/vector space/basis/frame/coordinate system

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces, coordinate-systems, affine-geometry

I am trying to understand the exact relation between all these things:

- point
- vector
- [affine space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space)
- [vector space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space)
- [basis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_%28linear_algebra%29)
- [frame](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_%28linear_algebra%29)
- [coordinate system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_system)

Can you explain me rigorously (in the mathematical sense) all the inter-relations existing between these geometrical concepts?

Additionnally, a strange thing is that this [french wikipedia article](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rep%C3%A8re_%28math%C3%A9matiques%29) seems to define a frame as a basis + origin whereas this [english wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_of_a_vector_space) seems to define the relation between a frame and a basis completely differently. So could you explain me the right relation between a basis and a frame (and why one of the article may be erroneous).

Comment: Which of this concepts you have trouble with? Do you know the elementary set theory? Linear algebra? If not, pick up any book on linear algebra and start reading.

Comment: I have good notions of set theory and linear algebra and I do not have big problem on these concepts taken separetely. But I do not have a clear picture of how to assemble and construct a coherent landscape with these concepts.

Comment: @Vincent I highly recommend you take a look at Linear Algebra and Geometry by Igor R. Shafarevich & Alexey O. Rezimov. It explains and describes the relationships between all these structures very lucidly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An affine space consists of points. The associated vector space contains the translations as mappings of the point space. So in a certain sense, the affine space is a representation of the additive group part of the vector space. The multiplicative part of the vector space then allows to construct lines and segments in the affine space.

For a frame you have to distinguish between linear algebra and differential geometry, where a moving frame is indeed a basis that may depend on the point in some smooth fashion. For instance along a curve the tangent, direction to center of curvature and the cross product of both form a moving frame, or on a surface a basis of the tangent space and the normal.

But I think you are interested in frames in linear algebra and functional analysis. In finite dimension, any basis has that many elements and if you take a generating set with more elements, you have non-trivial linear combinations of the null vector. In infinite dimensions, that relationship breaks down, you can have generating sets of Hilbert spaces that do not form a basis, and that also can not be reduced to a basis by taking a subset of it. That is where the definition of a frame comes in. As a geometric picture, in a frame there is a minimal positive angle between the frame vectors (all signs, or the lines through them). For further details like frame constants and dual frames see [wikipedia on frames of vector spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_of_a_vector_space).